# Why does VS Studio Code insert code I do not want when typing?

Tags: javascript, loops, visual-studio-code, getelementsbyname

I'm puzzled as to why the suggested code that pops up with in vs studio takes over when  I'm typing the following code;

x[i].style.color = 'red';

it takes over just after 'style' is typed and I hit the period button.  Quite annoying.

Below is the block of code I'm running:

```
function myFunction() {
  let x, i;
  x = document.querySelectorAll('.para');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

This is what happens in the editor, it wants to insert 'getElementsByClassName':

```
function myFunction() {
  let x, i;
  x = document.querySelectorAll('.para');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].getElementsByClassName.
  }
}
```

Comment: if you just typed `x[i].` it would only suggest getElementsByClassName if you typed `x[i].getE`, and then pressed enter, you should type `s` after the dot and continue to type style and not press enter as it won't be on IntelliSense because it won't know that its an domelement unless the for loop is evaluated, personally I turn it all off in settings.json `"editor.quickSuggestions": false,` as most of the time its just a distraction and no use (in the unlikly event you want to show it press Ctrl+Spacebar)

Comment: It's probably an autocomplete extension that kicks in, just hit the button whenever you don't like what autocomplete is giving you, and carry on.